# Java webstart application fails to load from browser, but works fine from the comand line

Tags: java, security, browser, command-line, java-web-start

If I do javaws myProgram.jnlp I can get the program to load like normal, but if I open the file from the browser, it just hangs and then closes. I have the webstart console pop up and I have an argument in my jnlp file for verbose output, but I get no notice of why it does not load the application. What could be the difference from loading from the browser and loading from the command line?

Comment: Probably browser security is the issue. Is the JWS program signed? Are you loading it from a file or from a web site? All these things enter into it. Can you run JWS programs in the browser from other web sites? If not, then it's a browser configuration issue.

Comment: I signed all my jar files. I am loading it from a file that the browser points to.

Comment: Most browsers use quite severe security restrictions for content loaded from the local file system (because this is a common attack vector for malware). Try loading from a website (even `http://localhost/` is likely to be treated more leniently).